# NSURLSession post : difference between uploadTask and dataTask

Tags: ios, http, post, background-process, nsurlsession

These are my two examples :

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                        "User-Agent": UIDevice.currentDevice().model]


        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://XXX"))
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let valuesToSend = ["key":value, "key2":value]
        var error: NSError?
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(valuesToSend, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
        request.HTTPBody = data

        if error == nil {
            let task = NSURLSession(configuration: config).dataTaskWithRequest(request,
                completionHandler: {data, response, error in

                if error == nil {
                    println("received == \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
                }
            })

            task.resume()

        } else {
            println("Oups error \(error)")
        }
```

AND the second

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                        "User-Agent": UIDevice.currentDevice().model]


        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://XXX"))
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let valuesToSend = ["key":value, "key2":value]
        var error: NSError?
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(valuesToSend, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)

        if error == nil {

            let task = NSURLSession(configuration: config).uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data,
                completionHandler: {data, response, error in

                if error == nil {
                    println("received == \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
                }
            })

            task.resume()


        } else {
            println("Oups error \(error)")
        }
```

So I wonder : what are the differences between these twos examples and what about the better for my case ( simple post and reception )

The two are in background no ? So ?

Comment: Have you tried using them and seeing the actual effect in a real compiled code?

Comment: Yep. It's on a real project that check user authentification. I didn't saw any differences.

Answer (score 6):

From [`NSURLSession` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:):

> `dataTaskWithRequest:`
>
> Creates an HTTP request based on the specified URL request object. `-
>   (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request`
>   **Parameters**
>
> *request*
>
> An object that provides request-specific information such as the URL,
>   cache policy, request type, and body data or body stream.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The new session data task.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume
>   method.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>
> `NSURLSession.h`

---

> `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:`
>
> Creates an HTTP request for the specified URL request object and
>   uploads the provided data object. `- (NSURLSessionUploadTask
>   *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request fromData:(NSData *)bodyData`
>   **Parameters**
>
> *request*
>
> An `NSURLRequest` object that provides the URL, cache policy, request
>   type, and so on. The body stream and body data in this request object
>   are ignored.
>
> *bodyData*
>
> The body data for the request.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The new session upload task.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its `resume`
>   method.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>
> `NSURLSession.h`

And additionally, [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) says:

> **`NSURLSessionDataTask`**
>
> This task issues HTTP GET requests to pull down data from servers. The
>   data is returned in form of `NSData`. You would then convert this data
>   to the correct type `XML`, `JSON`, `UIImage`, `plist`, etc.
>
> ```
> NSURLSessionDataTask *jsonData = [session dataTaskWithURL:yourNSURL
>       completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
>                           NSURLResponse *response,
>                           NSError *error) {
>         // handle NSData
> }];
> ```

---

> **`NSURLSessionUploadTask`**
>
> Use this class when you need to upload something to a web service
>   using `HTTP POST` or `PUT` commands. The delegate for tasks also
>   allows you to watch the network traffic while it's being transmitted.
>
> Upload an image:
>
> ```
> NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6);
>
> NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask =
>   [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request
>                               fromData:imageData];
> ```
>
> Here the task is created from a session and the image is uploaded as
>   `NSData`. There are also methods to upload using a file or a stream.

However your question remains quite ambiguous and too broad, since you haven't explained an explicit, specific problem and you could easily find this information by searching a little bit.

Comment: HTTP newbie here... What happens if I issue a `dataTaskWithRequest()`, passing a request configured to `POST`? I am sending credentials to the server over https for the first time, in order to get a token. I appended the credentials (JSON) to the request's body, and set the Authroization header for the whole `NSURLSession`. The sample code in your answer for upload task uses an image payload. I don't know if it applies to my case, but I still want to use `POST`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari: "Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects. Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests from your app to a server. Data tasks can return data to your app one piece at a time after each piece of data is received, or all at once through a completion handler."  see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html so yeah you can use it.

Comment: I don't think the question is ambiguous at all. The question is for the exact code posted and whether or not there is a difference in passing the JSON body data in the URLRequest with a dataTask vs passing the JSON body data in an uploadTask. Nothing from the Apple docs definitively answer if there is a difference or suggestion in which route to take here.

Answer (score 0):

I [asked](https://github.com/apple/swift-http-types/issues/15#issuecomment-1874581074) the same question to an Apple engineer:

> Do you know what the difference is between using `URLSessionDataTask` vs. `URLSessionUploadTask` for short-lived requests with bodies?

[@guoye-zhang](https://github.com/guoye-zhang) from Apple [said](https://github.com/apple/swift-http-types/issues/15#issuecomment-1874587956):

> Upload task is a subclass of data task, so there is little difference between the 2 of them. It's recommended to use upload task instead of `httpBody`/`httpBodyStream` properties on the `URLRequest`. Upload/download tasks also have the benefit of working with background sessions (but you'll have to use the delegate instead of the convenience or async methods).