# What's the difference between request.httpBody and URLSession.share.upload(with:from:)

Tags: swift, http, post, urlsession

I am using URLSession in swift to send post to my webservice with php, the php get the data from $_POST["varname"].

I found put the var in request.httpBody works, and put the var in data in uploadData(with:from:) also works.

So, what's the difference between these two ways? Which one should I prefer?

The php service is PHP7, swift is version4.

Example for httpBody style:

```
private func read(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://mywebservice.com/index.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let string = "username=user1&password=password1"
    request.httpBody = string.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
        //do with data from server
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Example for data style:

```
private func read2(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://mywebservice.com/index.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let string = "username=user1&password=password1"
    let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: data){ (data, response, error) in
        //do with data from server
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The upload request forces you to provide data (notice you have a ! in the second one). Other than that, I don't think there is much of a difference in your particular case. Personally I would go with the safer first approach and reserve the upload task for things like file uploads.

Comment: Difference between `uploadTask` and `dataTask`, better isn't? if so,
have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25505559/1244597

Comment: Thanks, after reading the document from Apple, I think the differece of these two methods is obviously, especial that uploadTask can be put in background queue while dataTask cann't.

Comment: Wireshark show the fram are same!